# List in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to declare  Page scope array  and fill from end user

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    String Knowledge_iloes = TextBox5.Text;
    Knowlege.Add(Knowledge_iloes);
    for (int i = 0; i < Knowlege.Count; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(Knowlege[i]);
    }
}
```

![ https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3HlU.jpg][1]

Comment: dont use response.write in the button method instead have the loop in the aspx page?

Comment: what can i use instead of response.write ?

Comment: depends, can you post your aspx? something like <% for (int i = 0; i < Knowlege.Count; i++) %> <div><% Knowlegde[i] %> </div>

Comment: really you should bind to a control of some sort, depends on your coding style

Comment: also what you are trying to acheieve

Comment: No ,it,s only to show list content ,my problem that the list is declare every time  i  press add

Comment: sorry I don't understand the question then